# Editing/Viewing KDE activity config files

Tags: 13.10, kubuntu, configuration, database, kde4

Is there a good way to edit your activities in a list, and edit other attributes about them?

Like have particular applications launch on specific viewports/geometries with `wmctrl` when an activity is first started (after boot) ?

This is what I've done so far:

I found that there was a database file at

```
~/.kde/share/apps/activitymanager/resources/
```

and I wanted to know how to open it.

Kexi reports the following:

```
Database project "~/.kde/share/apps/activitymanager/resources/database" does not appear to have been created using Kexi and cannot be opened.
It is an SQLite file created using other tools.
```

While opening it with Kate, I was told that the document had changed as I was viewing it.

I've installed SQLite, and got mostly uninterpretable lists and what I assume is hex.

I'm assuming that this file (and the other database file at `~/.kde/share/apps/activitymanager/activityranking`) are system files.

Is it best not to touch them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqliteman as a GUI tool for accessing generic SQLite 3 files (http://sqliteman.com).

Kexi currently supports SQLite-based files it created.